# Call function when program is killed

Tags: c++

I run some of my C++-programs on a HPC, scheduled using SLURM. Sometimes my programs get killed, either because they are using too many resources, or because they run too long. Usually, if my program is finished running, or encounters an internal error, I get a message telling me that fact, and I can apply appropriate actions.
But if my program is killed by the queue manager, I do not get any messages (and yes, I specified that I would like to get those messages in the job file, but somehow that does not work properly). Thus I was wondering if there is a possibility to call a function within the program when encountering the kill signal, or another way to tell me when my main program is killed?

Comment: IIRC the kill signal isn't interceptable

Comment: If your program is killed by SIGKILL (aka -9). Then there is *nothing* you can do. The kernel is going to terminate your process with a vengeance. Other signals like SIGTERM (-15) you *can* catch and *try* to do something with.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if my program is killed by SIGKILL or SIGTERM?

Comment: @arc_lupus for signals you *can* catch, sure. For something like SIGKILL, *no* - you are already dead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could look the other way around. Stop your program a bit before its end, and do your duty to produce a clean exit. With slurm you can use :

```
#SBATCH --signal=B:USR1@120
```

to send a signal to your bash script 120 seconds prior its job limit. Just trap this signal and produce a clean exit.

I use it, and it works very well.

```
#!/bin/bash -l

# job name
#SBATCH --job-name=example

# replace this by your account
#SBATCH --account=...

# one core only
#SBATCH --ntasks=1

# we give this job 4 minutes
#SBATCH --time=0-00:04:00

# asks SLURM to send the USR1 signal 120 seconds before end of the time limit
#SBATCH --signal=B:USR1@120

# define the handler function
# note that this is not executed here, but rather
# when the associated signal is sent
your_cleanup_function()
{
    echo "function your_cleanup_function called at $(date)"
    # do whatever cleanup you want here
}

# call your_cleanup_function once we receive USR1 signal
trap 'your_cleanup_function' USR1

echo "starting calculation at $(date)"

# the calculation "computes" (in this case sleeps) for 1000 seconds
# but we asked slurm only for 240 seconds so it will not finish
# the "&" after the compute step and "wait" are important
sleep 1000 &
wait
```

Those lines were extracted from [here](https://hpc-uit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jobs/examples.html)